# Zend Lucene Search

Tags: php, zend-framework

What could cause differences in the way Zend Lucene indexes the same data on two different servers?

I've found that the use of `glibc` vs `libiconv` might be one possible culprit, but are there any others?

I've indexed the same database on two servers, using identical PHP code - one on my local dev machine and one on the production server, and the results differ in some small but important ways (mainly results not being returned when they should be).

I've then uploaded the (correct) index files from my local server to the live server and the missing results are included - so it's pretty obviously something affecting the indexing.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.